# Getting the text from a hashtable of textboxes

Tags: c#, excel, textbox, hashtable

I am iterating through a hash table of textboxes and writing the output to an excel file. When it writes to the excel file the output is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 4.0.  I only want it to write out 4.0.  How do I get only the 4.0 and not the System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:  written to excel.  I thought there would be a suggestion of .text, but none appears and when I do that I get an error.  Here is my code

Adding to Hash Table

```
        tableOfTextBoxes.Add("LeftParameteDxOne", this.LeftParameteDxOne);
        tableOfTextBoxes.Add("LeftParameteDxTwo", this.LeftParameteDxTwo);
        tableOfTextBoxes.Add("LeftParameteDxThree", this.LeftParameteDxThree);
```

Printing to excel file

```
            row = 1;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in tableOfTextBoxes)
            {
                row++;
                workSheet.Cells[row, "B"] = pair.Value;  //how to get this only print out 4.0
            }
```

Comment: Why use a `Hashtable`? Why not use a strongly-typed generic `Dictionary`?

Comment: What are the advantages of using a Dictionary over a Hashtable?  I am using a Hashtable because it is O(1).

Comment: A dictionary is `O(1)` as well (or at least very close), and it can be strongly-typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to cast to a TextBox to get the text value:

```
row = 1;
foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in tableOfTextBoxes)
{
    row++;
    workSheet.Cells[row, "B"] = ((TextBox)pair.Value).Text;  //how to get this only print out 4.0
}
```

Note that if your collection was a generic `Dictionary<string, TextBox>` then the cast would not be necessary.